# SOAP requests with multiple namespaces

Tags: python, soap, spyne

I am in the process of implementing some pre-defined WSDL which uses multiple namespaces.  For simplicity, I have requests that look something like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
  </soapenv:Header>                                                                                                                                                      
  <soapenv:Body>
<a:Foo xmlns:a="www.example.com/schema/a" AttrA="a1" AttrB="b2">
    <b:Baz xmlns:b="www.example.com/schema/b" AttrC="c3"/>
  <a:Bar>blah</a:Bar>
</a:Foo>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've been using code like:

```
from spyne.model.primitive import Unicode
from spyne.model.complex import Iterable, XmlAttribute, ComplexModel, ComplexModelMeta, ComplexModelBase
from spyne.service import ServiceBase
from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap11
from spyne.application import Application
from spyne.decorator import srpc, rpc

class BazBase(ComplexModelBase):
    __namespace__ = "www.example.com/schema/b"
    __metaclass__ = ComplexModelMeta

class Baz(BazBase):
    Thing = Unicode
    AttrC = XmlAttribute(Unicode)

class FooService(ServiceBase):
    __namespace__ = "www.example.com/schema/a"

    @rpc(XmlAttribute(Unicode), XmlAttribute(Unicode), Baz, Unicode, _returns=Iterable(Unicode))
    def Foo(ctx, AttrA, AttrB, Baz, Bar):
        yield 'Hello, %s' % Bar 

app = Application([FooService],                                                                                                                                          
    "www.example.com/schema/a",
    in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
    out_protocol=Soap11(),
)
```

to parse things, but I get:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<senv:Envelope xmlns:senv="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <senv:Body>
    <senv:Fault>
      <faultcode>senv:Client.SchemaValidationError</faultcode>
      <faultstring>
      &lt;string&gt;:1:0:ERROR:SCHEMASV:SCHEMAV_ELEMENT_CONTENT:
      Element '{www.example.com/schema/b}Baz': This element
      is not expected. Expected is one of (
      {www.example.com/schema/a}Baz,
      {www.example.com/schema/a}Bar ).</faultstring>
      <faultactor></faultactor>
    </senv:Fault>
  </senv:Body>
</senv:Envelope>
```

as the response.

I've tried using the schema_tag parameter, but nothing I put in there seems to work, with errors like 'ValueError: Unhandled schema_tag / type combination.' or 'ValueError: InvalidTagName'

What do I need to do to properly handle multiple namespaces in the same request document?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Spyne does the right thing there and the request is incorrect. Child elements are always under parent's namespace. The children to those elements can be in own namespace.

```
<a:Foo xmlns:a="www.example.com/schema/a" AttrA="a1" AttrB="b2">
    <a:Baz xmlns:b="www.example.com/schema/b" AttrC="c3"/>
    <a:Bar>blah</a:Bar>
</a:Foo>
```

That said, you can just use the soft validator which doesn't care about namespaces.